# Calculate Average Time Between Dates in Dictionary

Tags: python, date, dictionary, datetime, time

I am trying to calculate the average time between (sorted, distinct) dates. These dates are stored in lists, which are kept as values in a dictionary (the keys are unique identifiers), like this:

```
my_dict = {'001':[datetime.date(2014, 7, 29), datetime.date(2014, 8, 1), datetime.date(2014, 8, 5), datetime.date(2014, 8, 13)], '002':[datetime.date(2014, 7, 29), datetime.date(2014, 8, 1), datetime.date(2014, 8, 5), datetime.date(2014, 8, 13)]...}
```

Here is the code I wrote for this:

```
for j,k in dicts.items():
    for i in range(0,len(k)):
        y = timedelta(days=0)
        x = k[i] - k[i-1]
        y = y + x
        n = len(k)
        score = y/n
        dicts.update({j:score})
```

However, when I compare the values I get to the data they seem to be incorrect, but I'm not sure why that would be. Can someone point me to what I'm doing wrong here?

EDIT: By incorrect I mean the average is incorrect. For example 10008 spits out '10008': datetime.timedelta(days=33, seconds=57600). But the dates for that entry are 11/25/2012, 3/30/2013, 7/92013, all more than 33 days apart.

Comment: wdym `seem to be incorrect`?

Comment: Indexing to `k[i-1]` will wrap around to the _last_ element of `k` when `i==0`, is that really what you wanted?  If not iterate on `range(1,len(k))` instead, and don't forget to adjust your `n` accordingly (n elements list means n-1 deltas)

Comment: Please show some sample output and explain what is incorrect about it.

Comment: For example 10008 spits out '10008': datetime.timedelta(days=33, seconds=57600). But the dates for that entry are 11/25/2012, 3/30/2013, 7/92013, all more than 33 days apart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, the average gap in times is equal to the first and last difference divided by the number of gaps. So if you don't need anything else just use the first and last divided buy the number of intervals. For example if you have 7/10, 7/20, and 7/30 your average gap is 10 days. if you change 7/20 to 7/12 you still have an average of 10 days.

That aside, in case you need other data as you work, here is the proper loop:

```
my_dict = {'001':[datetime.date(2014, 7, 10), datetime.date(2014, 7, 20), datetime.date(2014, 7, 30)], '002':[datetime.date(2014, 7, 29), datetime.date(2014, 8, 1), datetime.date(2014, 8, 5), datetime.date(2014, 8, 23)]}
import datetime
for j,k in my_dict.items():
    y = datetime.timedelta(days=0)  # need to move outside of loop so you can increment y
    for i in range(1, len(k)):  # need to skip first one to only measure intervals
        x = k[i] - k[i-1]
        y += x
        n = len(k) - 1
        score = y/n
        my_dict.update({j:score})
print(my_dict)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can solve this by changing this line:

`for i in range(0,len(k)):`

To this line:

`for i in range(1,len(k)):`

This is because in the first time you iterate through the code in your second nested for loop, this line `x = k[i] - k[i-1]` will result in `x = k[0] - k[-1]` which will calculate the difference between the first item and the last item in the list. Whereas what I think you wanted to do was calculate the difference between the first item and the second item in the list.

But if you change the code as suggested, then the first line will evaluate to `x = k[1] - k[0]` which I think is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I see a potential problem. You start at i=0, when you have `x = k[i]- k[i-1]` you are subtracting the last element from the first element. This will result in a negative value. You could use the abs() function to fix this.

You could use a while loop instead:

```
i = len(k) - 1
while i >= 0:
    # Insert rest of code
    i -= 1
```